# How can I add the ability for users to update an address that is specific to that sub-site?

Tags: 2013, list, sub-site

My idea is to have a simple form that users can fill in the company name, address, city, etc... This information would be displayed on the home page of the subsite.

Is there a method to do this in SharePoint 2013? Or does it require custom code?

I could use a custom list as long as there is the ability to limit the number of rows to be created at 1.  Is this possible?

Comment: Relevant question: Do you have access to InfoPath?

Comment: No...we do not. I am assuming it can be done in Infopath..?

Comment: It's easier done at least :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JavaScript to only display the first item in the list on the front page of the site.  For the list itself I am planning on using jQuery to hide the New item buttons.  That way all the users can do is edit the one that is existing.